# Lubuntu keeps on installing as if it is in a loop

Tags: system-installation, system, usb-installation

Why does Lubuntu keep on installing? Goes into a loop. Gets to the point where is says you must reboot now. I click the reboot button and lo and behold, it starts installing again. What must I do? I am at the end of my tether here.

Comment: Remove the USb stick is usually the solution to this weird behavior, my guess is your system is booting again and again from the USB

Answer (score 4):

Remove the installation media when prompted.